# DTO's, DAO or Service layer?

Tags: java, spring, architecture, n-tier-architecture

My application is based on the typical 3-tier layer architecture and the goal is to create a SpringMVC site and a Spring Batch solution which feeds and maintains our database's products and stock, where speed is a very important factor.

I'm using Spring's **JdbcTemplate** to manage a legacy database. Some of my tables contains lots of columns I don't use, and retrieving the whole rows has shown a negative impact due to the size of some fields (blobs we don't even need to map), so I created some beans matching the columns I want to retrieve, such as:

- **Product** -- Contains a 1:1 relation with the fields stored in the DB.
- **ProductDetailsView** -- Contains id, name, price, description, stock.
- **ProductListItemView** -- Id, Price, name, stock.

The DAO layer returns these beans to the service layer. AFAIK creating a DTO to expose it in my services interface for **Product** might make sense, but,

1) What about **ProductDetailsView** and **ProductListItemView**?

2) Should I do a 1:1 mapping from these 'views' or 'projections'  into DTOs with the same attributes? Why?

3) In any case, where would you place **JSR-303** annotations to validate the web's input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the use of DTO is due to decouple the entities from the view, then any internal change in the database won't impact the view or the clients and views does not require to change at all. Unless you require to send more or different information. But you are not using JPA you are using jdbctemplate so your objects could act immediately as a DTO as you are not tied to your database model.

For the Product entity it seems that the creation of a DTO is a good approach as your view object is only a partial representation of the entire object stored in the database.

1. I see that there is a minimum number of columns there in ProductDetailsView and ProductListItemView, (probably you just put a set), if you consider you wont have much changes in the definition of the tables, as they are not so big you could use the entities objects like a rest repository approach.
2. Projections is also a different approach to solve the same requirement avoiding send the information that does not matter to the view, but you will contains jackson annotations and jpa annotation in the same POJO. (This is more when you are using an ORM). People dont like that so much, that is why the approach to create the DTO's
3. Normally JSR303 annotations belongs to the 'input' objects, they are checking as soon as they reach the controller, you could use the `@Validated` annotations that play very well with springmvc and jsr, this is used in the methods that belong to your endpoints.

I think there is not a golden rule, but I will try to decouple the view of the database layer the much that I can. And as you are using jdbcTemplate you dont need to worry about bring entire representation or have issues with eager/lazy collections of the table, as you can always modify the projection to use get what you will use. Consider bring from the DAO the DTO that you will send to the view and use the same as an input object in your CRUD operations

Comment: Hello, thanks for your really useful answer, really appreciate it. 

In the case we used the results retrieved in the DAO as inmediate DTOs but we needed specific DTO's  in the service layer (let's say we need to add some field calculated in a service layer to one of these minified versions of an entity), where would we place and how'd we name both of these types of DTO in the project?

Some examples I can think of right now:

`org.company.project.catalog.model.view.ProductListItemView`
`org.company.project.catalog.dto.ProductListItemDto`
`org.company.project.common.dto.ProductListItemDto`

Comment: If If were you, I use a POJO will all the properties that I need within the service layer (where you store the calculations values) + properties that I retrieve from the database, I will call it exactly with the name of the database table within the model.jdbc package.   The DTO that I will send to the view use the first POJO values just to move the needed values to the presentation layer, and in this DTO define the json annotations or view annotations, I will put this DTO in the dto folder within the application module package